# SetState to a String returns null, Firestore with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a splash screen where I want to control the followig:
1. If user is loged out, take the user to OnBoardingScreen.
2. If user is loged in, but has no data in firestore. Take the user to SetupAccountPage
3. If user is loged in and had data to go to HomePage.
My problem is the string value(_controller) returns null. when the user is loged out and works fine when the user is loged in. I'm confused. I gave the code some time to load but doesn't help.

Please help for anyone who has an idea what is wrong here. 
Below is my code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:app/model/user.dart';
import 'package:app/pages/HomePage.dart';
import 'package:app/pages/SetupAccountPage.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/home/home.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/onboarding.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/setup_profile.dart';
import 'package:app/shared/loading.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  //FirebaseUser user;
  String onlineUserId;
  String _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkUser();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      print('done');
      if (_controller == 'out') {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => OnBoardingScreen(),
          ),
        );
      } else if (_controller == 'info') {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SetupAccountPage(),
          ),
        );
      } else if (_controller == 'home') {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomePage(),
          ),
        );
      }
      ;
    });
  }

  _checkUser() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;

    if (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() == null) {
      setState(() {
        _controller = 'out';
      });
    } else {
      final snapShot =
          await Firestore.instance.collection('Users').document(user.uid).get();
      if (snapShot.exists) {
        setState(() {
          _controller = 'home';
        });
        // Document with id == docId doesn't exist.
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _controller = 'info';
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.redAccent),
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        radius: 50.0,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.shopping_cart,
                          color: Colors.greenAccent,
                          size: 50.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'this is a name',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 24.0),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'another name',
                      softWrap: true,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer. The reson was geting the user was returning a future and this was the missing code.

```
Future<FirebaseUser> getUser() async {
    return await _auth.currentUser();
  }
```

Comment: It's ironic that you did `final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();` and all you had to do was check if that user was null